# Partial Fractions Variables

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\int\frac{x^3+6x^2+3x+16}{x^3+4x}\,dx$$

Eventually one solves that a variable (I used $C$) ${}= -x$.
By variables I mean the decomposition yields $A + Bx+C$.
Therefore $C = -1$.

I think that $C$ should equal $-x$. How is what I think not possible?

Comment: what do you mean by decomposition? Do you mean long division (or syntactic division)? The highest power of numerator and denominators are both 3, so after long division you get $1+ ...$

Comment: In partial fraction decomposition one gets that the integral is equal to  $\int $ $A\over (x)$ + $Bx+C\over (x^2+4)$ $dx$ .

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition requires that the degree in the numerator be less than that of the denominator. Hence, first use polynomial long division to get $1 +$ a polynomial remainder over the given denominator.

Comment: In this case though, you should get $ \int 1 + \frac{A}{x} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2 + 4}$. According to your decomposition, C shouldn't be a constant, hence it's not a partial fraction.

Comment: (added an explicit solution here)

Answer (score 0):

Partial fraction decomposition here only works because it is proven that if $P(x)$ is a polynomial, an expression

\begin{equation}
\frac{P(x)}{(x)(ax^{2}+b)}
\end{equation}

...can be put in the form:

\begin{equation}
\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{ax^{2}+b}
\end{equation}

...IF A, B, and C are constants. Otherwise, all bets are off.

It is possible that it works with C=-x in this case by coincidence, which you can check, but that's not a partial fraction decomposition; a partial fraction decomposition is one in which A, B, and C are constant.

I'll do the problem here:

First, factor the denominator so that it contains only one term:

\begin{equation}
x^{3}+4x=x(x^{2}+4)
\end{equation}

The goal is to find an A, B, and C (constants) such that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{3}+6x^{2}+3x+16}{x(x^{2}+4)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^{2}+4}
\end{equation}

Multiplying both sides by $x(x^{2}+4)$:
\begin{equation}
x^{3}+6x^{2}+3x+16=A(x^{2}+4)+(Bx+C)x=A(x^{2}+4)+Bx^{2}+Cx
\end{equation}
Plugging in x=0 will cancel everything on the right except the A term. The left will become 16:

\begin{equation}
16=A(4) \implies A=4
\end{equation}

Unfortunately, we can't use that strategy to find B and C, because there is no number which will make the A term 0. So I'll use a different strategy.

Working on the right hand side, I'll plug in A=4 because we know that now, and order everything by the power:

\begin{equation}
4(x^{2}+4)+Bx^{2}+Cx=4x^{2}+16+Bx^{2}+Cx=Bx^{2}+4x^{2}+Cx+16
\end{equation}

Coming back to the whole equation (having simplified the right side), we have:

\begin{equation}
x^{3}+6x^{2}+3x+16=Bx^{2}+4x^{2}+Cx+16
\end{equation}

This is the interesting part: The only way for these two to be equal for all x is if all the $x^{2}$ coefficients on the left sum to the $x^{2}$ coefficients on the right. So...

\begin{equation}
6=B+4 \implies B=2
\end{equation}
Now, same with the x coefficients:

\begin{equation}
3=C
\end{equation}

In conclusion,

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{3}+6x^{2}+3x+16}{x(x^{2}+4)}=\frac{4}{x}+\frac{2x+3}{x^{2}+4}
\end{equation}

This new function is easier to integrate. Split the second fraction into two fractions:

\begin{equation}
=\int \frac{4}{x}+\frac{2x}{x^{2}+4}+\frac{3}{x^{2}+4}dx
\end{equation}

With $u=x^{2}+4$, and dividing by 4 on the top and bottom of the 3rd fraction, this equals

\begin{equation}
4\int \frac{1}{x}dx+\int \frac{du}{u}+\int \frac{3/4}{(x/2)^{2}+1}dx
\end{equation}

Then the first two terms are just natural logs (see below). The rightmost term is an arctan.
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{x}dx=ln(x)+C 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{x^{2}+1}dx=arctan(x)+C 
\end{equation}